# Does sys.syslogins generate an incomplete list of SQL logins?

Tags: sql-server

I generated master.dbo.syslogins and sys.sql_logins for the auditors the other day. Today they asked me to explain why the SQL login accounts between the 2 listings did not match.

I'm not really sure how to answer this. My best guess is that there's certain service accounts which do not have SQL server logins and would therefore not show up on master.dbo.syslogins. But then I ran into a problem where there were SQL logins found on master.dbo.syslogins that were not listed on sys.sql_logins.

The documentation available online seems to suggest the same but they still felt it wasn't enough. Has anyone else had to answer a question like this before? How did you guys go about it?

Answer (score 0):

`sys.sql_logins` does not include Windows logins or certificate-mapped logins.  A closer match to the legacy `syslogins` would be:

```
select *
from sys.server_principals
where type in ( 'U','S','C')
```

Comment: Interesting. So sql_logins is deprecated as server_principals does pretty much everything it does at the principal level instead of logins.

I guess the workflow would be to use server_principals to identify the authentication type and then use sys.sql_logins to just focus on SQL authentication principals. Thanks so much.

Comment: 'G' as well (WINDOWS_GROUP) -- my guess is excluding 'R' (SERVER_ROLE) is more likely equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I believe `sp_helplogins` would helpful in your case, it would provides information about logins and the users associated with them from each database as quick reference and without any effort i.e. joining multiple system tables.